# sql - transferring columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given a table, what is the best way to take two columns and show two rows for each row? Here's an example:

```
declare @t table (
    id int,
    v1 nvarchar(max),
    v2 nvarchar(max),
    v3 nvarchar(max)
)
insert into @t
select 0, 'hello', 'there', 'filler'
union all select 1, 'hello', 'again', 'filler'
```

has a table like this:

```
0   hello   there   filler
1   hello   again   filler
```

... I'd like it to look like this:

```
0   hello   filler
0   there   filler
1   hello   filler
1   again   filler
```

I've tried to do an UNPIVOT, but given that I don't need to unpivot all columns, this hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT` to unpivot a subset of columns, rather than all:

```
declare @t table (
id int,
v1 nvarchar(max),
v2 nvarchar(max),
v3 nvarchar(max)
)
insert into @t
select 0, 'hello', 'there', 'filler'
union all select 1, 'hello', 'again', 'filler'

SELECT id, v, v3
FROM
(
  SELECT id, v1, v2, v3 
  FROM @t
) AS cp
UNPIVOT 
(
  v FOR vs IN (v1, v2)
) AS up;
```

Answer (score 1):

using `cross apply()` with `values()`:

```
select t.id, v.col1, v.col2
from @t t
  cross apply (values (v1,v3),(v2,v3)) v(col1,col2)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RMNJ58477

returns:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | col1  |  col2  |
+----+-------+--------+
|  0 | hello | filler |
|  0 | there | filler |
|  1 | hello | filler |
|  1 | again | filler |
+----+-------+--------+
```